# "Codecs" are marked as orphaned packages by APT after fresh OS install

Tags: apt, package-management, codecs, multimedia, restricted

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 with enabled "*Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats*" option in Ubiquity APT telling me (apt autopurge) these packages are not longer required:

```
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2
```

The first packages isnt needed cause chromium isnt avaiable as a .deb package but what with others ? I dont think they are unnecessary. I can simply type command below and these packages will not be marked as orphaned:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-vaapi libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2
```

but i want to know. Do i really dont need packages above ?
I see a meta-package "ubuntu-restricted-addons" isnt installed so Ubiquity installs always the same set of packages (on pc#1, pc#2, pc#3) to handle restricted formats (i dont mean graphics drivers cause they are different) ?

Comment: Yes, but Totem doesnt use any from this packages as a "codec" even though they are not totem dependencies ? When i installing codecs manually these packages are part of "ubuntu-restricted-addons" metapackage. Maybe its time for changes in this metapackage and re-write this metapackage if these packages are not required.

Comment: You asked if you "need" those packages *without mentioning Totem* or offering any use case. If you are using the software or codecs provided by those packages, then you should install them. If you are not, then your system won't be harmed by removal. If you have a disagreement with the dependencies of Totem, this is the wrong place to discuss.